# Could water soluble dyes be directly absorbed by a plant's / tree's xylem?

Tags: botany, trees, intracellular-transport

Amateur woodworker / hobbyist here, I enjoy using colorful or exotic wood species, the issue is that many of these species are rare, expensive, endangered, hard to grow, or otherwise difficult to obtain.

What I'm wondering is... is it possible to directly introduce dyes or color to a young tree slowly over time, either through directly exposing the internal rings to some kind of dyed water while its growing, or by somehow getting around the root's natural filters? (People have tried to grow plants in just dyed water, but the roots are able to filter most of it out)

It would be interesting to have a plank dyed with a more saturated color than is naturally possible, without treating it and introducing dyes after the wood has been felled.

Often times treating wood can damage specific properties of it, some dyes and treatments can make the planks virtually useless for sanding or staining, and reintroducing water or other fluids can cause warping and other damage to the wood.

If a natural, water soluble dye existed within the wood from the start, it might be possible to get around some or all of those issues.

I'm just wondering if this is even possible, and if so, how it could be done without killing a tree..

This is more of an idea then an experiment, but it would be interesting to try.

Comment: You could try using a small weed or hydrophilic species like willow and hydroponics. For bigger trees it would be possible using some obscure metholodology and highly cumbersome.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible; the roots have selective permeability. Try this: add food dye to water (darker is better), use it to water a cut stem and a rooted plant. The cut stem will take it up. The rooted plant will not.